# Bodies colliding multiple times in single contact [AndEngine]

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

In the game I'm developing, I have bodies (from the box2d extension) flying around. Some of these bodies collide with each other. The problem is that for every single contact the `beginContact` method in `contactListener` get called twice (at least).

Both the bodies that are colliding have the maximum elasticity of `1`.

Is there a way to make the collision happen exactly once, i.e., have `beginContact` called only once for every contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had created two identical bodies behind one another by mistake. Obviously, this caused the `beginContact` method to be called twice for each collision.

This must be one of the sneakiest bugs I have ever had.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue that matches your question as phrased (except with plain Box2D in C++, though that issue is generic to any Box2D binding), but the cause was different.
Two shapes that should have kept colliding registered an `EndContact` and a `BeginContact` very shortly after. The reason was that **one of the two shapes had `setType` called on its body** shortly after the collision began.
When `setType` actually changes the body type, any involved contacts are deleted and recreated. This causes the contact callbacks to be invoked again.
It appears that **older Box2D versions did not have this behavior**.

Placing a breakpoint on `EndContact` and inspecting the call stack can be helpful to debug this issue.